# TFS Build Services, environment variables and multiple build agents

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a MsBuild process that start as part of build using TFS Build Services 2013. I need to pass a few parameters to this process (for example the build number). I've done this previously by modifying the build template and added these parameters to the list of parameters sent into MSBuild, something that has worked fine.

I did however found that TFS Build Services writes [a number of environment variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448.aspx) for run (build number being one of them) and as I easily can change my MSBuild script I'd rather just use these directly variables instead of modifying the build template.

My question is however how this will work when I have several build agents? Won't they write over each others values in the environment variables? Can I be 100% certain in my MSBuild script that I didn't get the build number of the next build that might have started in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each TFS build is done using a specific build number. If you have multiple agents working on a 'parallel' build, they will all use the same build number. Each build agent will be running in their own specific environment and will not have any issue if other agents are running in parallel - the build number for one agent will not 'clobber' another during a build.

Comment: Each agent runs in is own process and environment variables.  So they will not conflict.  Those environment variables are not user/machine specific only process specific.